# scikit-learn GaussianMixture terminates right after initialization

Tags: scikit-learn

I use GaussianMixture to perform clustering of the feature vectors (8-dimensional).  I set up GaussianMixture as the following:

```
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=class_no,
                     tol=1e-6,
                     covariance_type="spherical",
                     init_params="random",
                     verbose=2, verbose_interval=1)
```

I have around 10 million sample vectors, and class_no is 100. GaussianMixture fitting then terminates prematurely after initialization.

If I reduce the number of samples to 1-2 millions, the fitting went properly.

What is the likely causes?

Also, I also see *ll change inf* in the first iteration (when it does not terminate prematurely).  Is that normal?

Comment: What's the error you get when it terminates? Have you managed to reproduce the problem with smaller amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I perhaps have found the problem after some more experiments.  If I run GM with 1M samples, the bottom shows the ll changes for the first 30 iterations.  The general trend is the ll change start very small, then it increase gradually to a peak, and it converges to zero.  As I increase the sample size, the ll changes in the first few steps are getting smaller and smaller.  By the time when I use 10M samples, the ll change in iteration 2 is already smaller than my threshold of 1e-6.  If I reduce it to 1e-7, it will finish like when I use smaller sample size.

Looks like we should normalize the ll-change with sample size somehow?

```
Initialization 0
  Iteration 1    time lapse 10.15743s    ll change inf
  Iteration 2    time lapse 7.76352s     ll change 0.00001
  Iteration 3    time lapse 7.83711s     ll change 0.00006
  Iteration 4    time lapse 7.83133s     ll change 0.00044
  Iteration 5    time lapse 8.18798s     ll change 0.00317
  Iteration 6    time lapse 7.78111s     ll change 0.02268
  Iteration 7    time lapse 7.95682s     ll change 0.13413
  Iteration 8    time lapse 7.87189s     ll change 0.38677
  Iteration 9    time lapse 7.75204s     ll change 0.53651
  Iteration 10   time lapse 7.73964s     ll change 0.46236
  Iteration 11   time lapse 7.75558s     ll change 0.55855
  Iteration 12   time lapse 7.75457s     ll change 0.57340
  Iteration 13   time lapse 7.77386s     ll change 0.21811
  Iteration 14   time lapse 7.75011s     ll change 0.09917
  Iteration 15   time lapse 7.78765s     ll change 0.06162
  Iteration 16   time lapse 7.81858s     ll change 0.04783
  Iteration 17   time lapse 7.76057s     ll change 0.04079
  Iteration 18   time lapse 7.73551s     ll change 0.03687
  Iteration 19   time lapse 7.82454s     ll change 0.03416
  Iteration 20   time lapse 7.78091s     ll change 0.02830
  Iteration 21   time lapse 7.78215s     ll change 0.02189
  Iteration 22   time lapse 7.75392s     ll change 0.01775
  Iteration 23   time lapse 7.77399s     ll change 0.01523
  Iteration 24   time lapse 7.73693s     ll change 0.01342
  Iteration 25   time lapse 7.74950s     ll change 0.01205
  Iteration 26   time lapse 7.73767s     ll change 0.01107
  Iteration 27   time lapse 7.79130s     ll change 0.01021
  Iteration 28   time lapse 7.76402s     ll change 0.00916
  Iteration 29   time lapse 7.77638s     ll change 0.00799
  Iteration 30   time lapse 7.76722s     ll change 0.00695
```